# Problem to compile the pgfmanual with lualatex

Tags: tikz-pgf

The next link gives the `pgf_2.10-CVS.tds.zip, pgf_2.10-CVS.pdf and pgf_2.10-CVS.ChangeLog` [pgfmanual CVS](http://altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html) with the version I found today (25/04/2012).

First the file `pgfmanual-en-main.tex` looks strange. I find

```
\begin{document}

\include{pgfmanual-en-gd-overview}
\include{pgfmanual-en-gd-usage-tikz}
\include{pgfmanual-en-gd-trees}
\include{pgfmanual-en-gd-layered}
\include{pgfmanual-en-gd-force}
\include{pgfmanual-en-gd-circular}
\include{pgfmanual-en-gd-misc}
\include{pgfmanual-en-gd-new-algorithms}
\include{pgfmanual-en-gd-implementation}

\end{document}
```

inside the document I kept the first line `\begin{document}` and removed others lines. Then I compiled with pdflatex, the result is at the link above.

I tried to compile with lualatex, the whole document or only the part about graphs but I got different mistakes. With the whole document, I got a pgfmath error `5mm and 5mm` with `a` or `an` is not a function.

With only the graphs, I got

```
  LaTeX Warning: Reference `section-last-graphdrawing-library-in-manual' on page 4 undefined on input line 28.

  ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
  <to be read again> 
               \unhbox 
  l.39 \end{codeexample}
```

Perhaps I don't know how to compile with lualatex but the last time, I have not had any problems. Do you have some ideas to compile this big document with lualatex ?

Comment: Where did you you download this new version? (I don't mean your website ;-) )

Comment: here http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=142562  but you download it from my site. You click  on the zip icon. http://altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html  The pgfmanual is only incomplete ( I don't have the graph's sections ). If you want directly the cvs : `cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/pgf co -P pgf`

Comment: @Altermundus Did you solve the issue? If you did, please tell how or add some more information.

Comment: @Altermundus This is linked to a codedoc bug with auto-xref (see bug tracker http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3522224&group_id=142562&atid=752792).

Answer (score 1):

As of November 1st, the bug report is closed as *Fixed* by Christian Feuersänger with the following remark:

> I have improved the robustness of the auto-cross-referencing: it will no longer fail in the presence of spaces here.
>
> However, I did not fix the fact that it should not consider a cross-reference for the concatenated list at all.

The link to the bug page is given in cjorssen's comment above.