# Highlight LaTeX code and presenting results as in a manual

Tags: pgfplots, listings, highlighting, documentation, code

I would like to write a short guidelines of LaTeX for my students. In the spirit of some LaTeX manuals, I'd like to present the code and the result as follows,

[image: Example from <code>pgfplots</code> manual]

This example illustrate more or less what I'd like to do.

**QUESTION(S)**

- Is the two-columns style realize with `minipage`?
- How could I insert the code in a way it shows highlighted?

Any help is welcome. Cheers.

Comment: This has been discussed here before so you can search for duplicates.

Comment: See the following [answer1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120830/code-examples-like-in-the-tikz-pgf-manual/120953#120953) and [answer2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file/114582#114582).

Comment: There's also [Is there a listings configuration for TikZ as used in PGF/TikZ manual?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72999/13304)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: Another thing that can be helpful (in this case especially) is to just *look* at the manual. It's source is in `tex-dist/source` and you cams just Find the text associated with the example, tracing back to the macro that makes it and viola! Perfect duplication.

Comment: This is a dupe of something: I've picked one!